# How to extract specific data from get_dict from Zillow API

Tags: python, zillow

I was able to successfully call and retrieve the dictionary data from the Zillow API.  Using PrettyPrint, I was able to retrieve a simple dictionary.  How do I extract specific data?  I tried running through keys after the get_dict like a normal dictionary but it didn't work.  I posted the result below and was wondering how I could pull just the 'amount' from the 'zestimate'.  I'm unfamiliar with how PrettyPrint and the get_dict function work together to pull values and keys.

```py
import zillow
import pprint

key = "<my key>"

address = "826 Entrada St, Bossier City, LA"
postal_code = "71111"

api = zillow.ValuationApi()
data = api.GetSearchResults(key, address, postal_code)

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
pp.pprint(data.get_dict())

{   'zestimate': {   'amount': 250405,
                     'amount_change_30days': 228,
                     'amount_currency': 'USD',
                     'amount_last_updated': '08/18/2019',
                     'valuation_range_high': 262925,
                     'valuation_range_low': 237885},
    'zpid': '109815226'}
```

Comment: `I tried running through keys after the get_dict like a normal dictionary but it didn't work`: What did you try?

Comment: I tried doing the same thing by print k, v for keys and values and that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

A previous contributor gave me a sample code but then deleted it.  His or her code was nearly complete.  The contributor told me to bind it to a normal dictionary and it will work.  And it worked!!!

```py
my_dict = data.get_dict()
amount = my_dict['zestimate']['amount']
print(amount)
```

Answer (score -1):

if d is the dictionary then you get the amount by: d["zestimate"]["amount"]
as d["zestimate"] returns another dictionary.